# Strategy for displaying a progress indicator while loading data into an SQLite database?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-listfragment

My app consists of the following components:

- a content provider for data stored in an SQLite database
- a `ListFragment` that uses `CursorAdapter` to display data from the content provider
- a service that runs in the background periodically polling a remote URI for new data, adding any to the database via the content provider

Here's the challenge. When the `ListFragment` is first displayed, the database is empty. I'm using `LoaderManager` / `CursorLoader` to fetch data from the provider while the `ListFragment` displays a progress indicator. The problem is that this will always result in an empty table since the service hasn't had time to poll the remote URI yet.

The user observes something like this:

- the `ListFragment` displays a progress indicator
- the progress indicator disappears and an empty list is displayed
- about 3 or 4 seconds later, the service finishes updating the data and it is displayed

This is not intuitive. I would like to keep the progress indicator displayed while the data is being loaded.

---

Here's an overview of what I've got right now.

```
public class ArticleListFragment extends ListFragment
        implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

    //...

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //...
        mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(...);
        setListAdapter(mAdapter);
        setListShown(false);
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new CursorLoader(...);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
        mAdapter.swapCursor(data);
        setListShown(true);
    }

    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ContentObserver technique and load cursor when data is changed. So you can hide the progress when you need, e.g. when Cursor.getCount() > 0.